# Enable systemd service with a parameter

Tags: systemd, service

I have a `systemd` service with a paramter. It's working great. However, I cannot start it without a parameter.

The parameter would look like `systemctl start my-service@1-0.service`, where the `1-0` would be parsed by a php script. The php script has a default of `1-0`, but I cannot start it with `systemctl start my-service@.service`. It tells me:

`Failed to start my-service@.service: Unit name my-service@.service is missing the instance name.`

I successfully enabled it with `systemctl enable my-service@.service`, but is it going to fail on boot? If so, how can I tell it to start with a default of `1-0` if nothing else is specified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that enabling a service with a default parameter is possible, per [this guide](https://gist.github.com/imerr/2eb1fa929757b3c5a145b208af18b115). Since it needs to default to `1-0`, I just did:

`systemctl enable my-service\@1-0.service`

It successfully created the symlink:

`Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/my-service@1-0.service → /lib/systemd/system/my-service@.service`

Thanks for the downvote btw. Stay classy.

"Fine... I'll do it myself." ~ Thanos